# Check is task will run in Gradle

Tags: gradle

```
gradlew update test
```

How to check if "test" task is present in list? I need this for "update" task, it read a file from resources if "test" will be and another file if "test" will not be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check `gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("test")`

@see [TaskExecutionGraph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html)